# how do we make user to enter the correct login of the website in android

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences, registration

How do we make a user to enter the correct login of the website in android

I am using shared preferences but it saves only when I enter the values locally.

I am making an app which signs up/ register me on the real website.

But I cannot do it.

Please help me on this

Comment: Your question seems vague, could you give more details ?

Answer (score 0):

Use FireBase, check this for more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth.

And here is a nice tutorial: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate with your own portal / website with your app and want user login from remote server you already have configured. you should use web service like REST etc you can find extensive details here [consuming REST services in android application](https://marwendoukh.wordpress.com/2017/02/01/consuming-rest-web-service-from-android/)

and you also can maintain to avoid user re login and switch it to main activity (where user reaches after login/signup) by checking login state of user on your portal / website and switch between activities with accordance